# How can I use "before" instead of "beforeAll"?

Tags: jestjs

I am migrating existing tests to Jest.

Can I use `before` instead of `beforeAll` in Jest?

What I'd do is in `jest.config.js`,

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  globals: {
    before: beforeAll,
  },
};
```

But how can I import beforeAll? `require('@jest/globals')` raises:

```
Error: Do not import `@jest/globals` outside of the Jest test environment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beforeAll` cannot be accessed in Jest config file because it and tests run in different processes. `globals` option is for serializable JSON values.

A correct place for this is a file specified in `setupFilesAfterEnv` config option:

```
global.before = beforeAll;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Estus. I tried `console.log(require(@jest/globals))` in a setup file. but it gives undefined for beforeAll.

Actually, all undefined except for `jest` ( `{
        afterAll: undefined,
        afterEach: undefined,
        beforeAll: undefined,
        beforeEach: undefined,
        describe: undefined,` ...
)

 Do you know how can I get beforeAll in a setupFile by any chance?

Comment: You don't need `@jest/globals` at all. More precisely, this needs to be done in setupFilesAfterEnv, as Jest enviroment is fully available there.

Comment: Thanks for your following up. `setupFilesAfterEnv` works. It was really helpful. Now I can migrate to jest easier